# How to find which program is accessing the webcam through audiodg.exe?

Tags: windows, audio, troubleshooting, webcam, microphone

A webcam's light has been intermittently coming on, and I'm trying to track down what program is accessing it (without just blindly killing programs until the light goes off).

I've gone through the standard steps: finding the "Physical Device Object" IDs in Device Manager, using Process Explorer to search open handles and which programs are accessing what, but this leads to "audiodg.exe" accessing the webcam handles, which is apparently the "Windows Audio Device Graph Isolation".

This is what's *directly* accessing the webcam, but I can't see what program called for its access in the first place, to see which program is pulling the puppet-strings, so to speak.

So is there a way to trace which program is accessing a webcam's microphone or video via "Windows Audio Device Graph Isolation", audiodg.exe?

Comment: [Find Which Program is Using Your Webcam Currently » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/webcam-which-program-using-device/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Could this be reopened please? I clarify how this question differs from the "duplicate" linked. I've already found the device IDs and searched for open handles, found the two programs that have the handles -- audiodg.exe and svchost.exe -- however, these are merely core OS programs/services and not the actual program that's calling the accessing.

Comment: If the linked duplicate question is not a duplicate, then your question isn't actually about determining what process is using your webcam, but rather what application triggered audiodg.exe (which *happens* to be using your webcam). Editing your question to focus on this would result in more useful answers for your situation.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Good point. Would it be better for me to start a new question for this given the amount of time that has passed since asking?

Comment: No. This one has no answers so it should be edited. Editing it will bump it to the front page so it will still be seen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I revised the question.